# iOS go to settings-app from within app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, settings.bundle

The guidelines state that you can have settings in app, or in the built-in settings-app. But is there any option to go the specific page in the settings app from within the application? (i.e. press a button and launch the settings app). Can you launch another app in iOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with 5.0, you were able to do this... but then Apple removed it in 5.1 and has said it's no longer supported :(.

Answer (score -2):

I just discovered that you can ask Siri to go to settings and she will take you to the settings for the current app. Of course that's no use from the programming perspective but useful tip